# iconv: cannot convert some strings from gb3212 to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, iconv

Good day! I have a problem with converting this string in gb3212: "е – с"
My actions:

```
[i.remen@win74 ~]$ iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8 tst.txt
е iconv: illegal input sequence at position 3
[i.remen@win74 ~]$
```

I tried many different versions(both from separate iconv and as part of glibc). Is there any way to to this conversion?

Comment: "illegal input sequence" means *"that file ain't no gb2312"*. Can you show us a hex dump of the file/string in question?

Comment: a7 d6 20 a8 43 20 a7 e3

Answer (score 5):

maybe some characters is not in gb2312 ,try gb18030,it's a 'bigger' charset than gb2312